# Show In Playlist functionality

Tags: windows, itunes

I frequently use the "Show In Playlist feature" to pick songs so I can play songs that I have not played before.  However, I have multiple copies of the same song - some are the same version, some are different renditions.

Is there a way I can select multiple songs and see all playlists that they appear on?

Comment: did you try renaming?

Comment: @Buscar웃, What do I rename?